# ¿Cómo llegó "coscarse" a significar "darse cuenta"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

[Coscarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B4AIh45) es un verbo pronominal que significa "darse cuenta" o "concomerse". De acuerdo al DRAE su etimología viene del latín *coxicare, de coxa*, 'cadera'.

*[Coxa](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/coxa)*, aparte de "cadera" puede significar el "primer segmento de la pata de los artrópodos".

¿Cómo llegó esta palabra entonces a ser usada como equivalente de "se va a dar cuenta"?

Answer (score 4):

No conocía el término, así que ofrezco esto solo como posibilidad. (*Coscarse* no es una palabra habitual en Chile, en ninguno de sus sentidos).

La onomatopeya '**cosc**' imita el ruido del golpe dado a un objeto duro. De ella derivarían (al menos según la etimología de Corominas, veo que la RAE piensa otra cosa) varias palabras relacionadas con el ruido de golpes: ***cuesco*** ("hueso de la fruta", "pedo"), ***coscurro*** ("pan duro"), ***escoscar*** ("pelar frutos secos"), ***cosquillas*** (aquí veo difícil encontrar una relación... mis disculpas), y ***coscorrón*** ("golpe de nudillos en la cabeza", al que los chilenos le decimos *coscacho*).

Estas palabras son de origen ibérico. Probablemente otras, las que tienen las raíces calc- y casc-, también sean onomatopéyicas, aunque son muy anteriores, las heradamos del griego y el latín.

Lo que yo veo es que *coscarse*, "darse cuenta de algo", puede surgir como un juego expresivo, de darte un golpe en la cabeza con la nueva idea.

Answer (score 0):

Coscarse, viene de coxicare, efectivamente del latín... Pero coxicare no viene de coxa... Coxicare es un verbo latino en sí mismo q significa sospechar o intuir... Y con el paso del tiempo, se fue generalizando a "darse cuenta de"

Además coxa, viene de coccix, que viene en el griego y significa pajaro cuco... Pues para los griegos la cadera tenia la forma del pico de esta ave... Siendo ademas coccix la onomatopeya del sonido de dicha ave

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish Language! Una respuesta interesante, pero ¿tienes alguna referencia que la apoye? ¿O es simplemente una idea que tienes? Ten en cuenta que para este tipo de preguntas normalmente es mejor si dispones de bibliografía, referencias o cualquier otra documentación que apoye tu argumentación.