# De donde viene la expresión "darse cuenta"?

Tags: etimología, méxico, hispanoamérica, español-neutral, rae

La traducción del español al ingles de "Me di cuenta de algo" es "I just realized something". "Realized" viene del francés que significa (más o menos) "hacer real" y el origen etimológico es comprensible.

En el caso de "darse cuenta (de algo)" no he encontrado el origen de la expresión. Lo más que he encontrado es que tiene mucha relación con la expresión "caer en (la) cuenta (de algo)" y en [una pregunta de este mismo foro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20731/c%C3%B3mo-lleg%C3%B3-coscarse-a-significar-darse-cuenta) la relacionan con "coscarse".

Por un lado "cuenta" viene de "contar" y está relacionada con los cálculos y el conteo de valores (bancos por ejemplo). También puede expresar causalidad, explicación de sucesos, o la forma en que se llegó a un resultado como en "rendir cuenta del balance monetario".

Otras formas de expresar está idea son "Percatarse", "advertir" y el mismo "coscarse", pero ninguna parece explicar con toda claridad el origen de la expresión.

¿Por qué se dice "darse cuenta"? ¿Por qué alguien caería en una cuenta? ¿Qué o cual es "la cuenta"?

Mientras escribo esto me doy cuenta (Válgame la ironía) de que "dar cuenta" es una forma posible de decir "rendir cuenta" si se fuerza lo suficiente. Siendo así, la misma expresión se puede emplear con dos significados distintos:

`Se dio cuenta de que se le acababa el tiempo para dar cuenta del balance.` que se puede escribir `Cayó en la cuenta de que se le acababa el tiempo para rendir cuenta del balance.`

En este sentido, cuando se habla de "la cuenta" se podría referir a un hecho desvelado por un conjunto de detalles. En la primera "cuenta" de la oración anterior, saber la hora límite de la entrega de las cuentas y cuanto tardará en terminar la entrega desvelan el hecho de que el tiempo empieza a ser un problema; en la segunda "cuenta", los movimientos desvelan y explican el resultado del balance.

Quiero hacer hincapié en que esto es una interpretación mía, pero sigue siendo una conjetura sin fundamentos. Seria interesante que, al final, "darse cuenta" y "caer en cuenta" solo sean otra evolución de la expresión "rendir cuentas".

Comment: I **just** realized something.= **Acabo** de darme cuenta de algo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La expresión actual "**darse cuenta**" es la suma de dos palabras que se han mantenido unidas, dando un sentido distinto al de su nacimiento, pues en última instancia provendría de una expresión antigua, "*dar buena cuenta (de algo)*", utilizando posteriormente la forma pronominal en el verbo "*dar*" (darse), y desapareciendo el adjetivo intermedio "*buena*" que los unía.

Por lo que he podido estudiar, la palabra "*darse cuenta*" proviene por una parte del latín "*computare*", que significa "*calcular*" o "*contar*". En el español antiguo, "*computare*" adquirió el sentido de "tener en cuenta", "considerar algo" o "*llevar la cuenta*" de algo, en su sentido narrativo.  Sin embargo, para solicitar la narración expresa de algo, se utilizaba conjuntamente el verbo "*dar*" que normalmente iba acompañada del adjetivo "*buena*" y la palabra "*cuenta*", en aquel sentido narrativo. Así habitualmente se decía "*dar buena cuenta de algo*" cuando se pedía que se "informara" o se "contara" algún suceso sin escatimar en los detalles.

Con el tiempo, la expresión "**darse cuenta**" evolucionó para referirse a la acción de tomar conciencia de algo, el adjetivo "*buena*" que iba intercalado desapareció pero la palabra "*cuenta*" en sentido narrativo, se mantuvo como parte de la expresión junto con el verbo "*dar*" en forma pronominal "*darse*", por lo que "*darse cuenta*" adquirió el sentido de "*advertir*" o "*percatarse*" uno mismo de algo.

Por lo tanto etimológicamente hablando, "*darse cuenta*" significa "*contarse a si mismo algo*" o de forma más detallada, "*dar buena cuenta de algo así mismo*", es decir, "*advertir*" los pormenores o minucias que están sucediendo, lo que se relaciona con una reflexión interna *más detallada*  y precisa para comprender o tomar conciencia de algo.

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez esta respuesta sea algo "circular", pero si consideramos que ["dar cuenta de"](https://www.rae.es/dpd/dar) significa "informar":

> Como no pronominal, *dar cuenta de una cosa o de una persona* significa [...] ‘informar a alguien sobre ella’: «Él me dio cuenta de que un francés había escrito una vida de aquel caballero fusilado» (Rojas Hidalgo [Esp. 1980]).

donde ["cuenta"](https://dle.rae.es/cuenta) tendría la acepción (5): [razón](https://dle.rae.es/raz%C3%B3n) (entendimiento)

el pronominal "darse cuenta de" significaría llegar a ese entendimiento uno mismo (percatarse, tomar conocimiento).